# Find wifi enabled devices [stations] around

Tags: wifi

Imagine this situation that there are some smartphones and computer around with their WiFi adapter (wireless adapters) on, but not necessary connected to a network.

Is there a way to look the MAC addresses via a Linux machine?

Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tool such as kismet, http://www.kismetwireless.net/, to scan for wireless networks. I believe it can show you all wireless devices in your vicinity without having to have the devices being actively connected to same network.

[image: kismet example]

This post should give you a rough idea of how to accomplish the scanning of the network using Kismet. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/beacon-frames-80211-devices-and-kismet/3279.

Also as a side note you can use this tool, fing, http://www.overlooksoft.com/fing, to find out all the `MAC` addresses of the devices on your network.

```
% sudo fing 10.9.8.0/24
```

[image: fing example]